# Weird XML Parsing with symbols

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLParsing to parse some XML Data.

I have one element called.... `<Email>abc@expressl&t.net</Email>`

So when `didStartElement` delegate respond to elementName Email

It will go in `foundCharacters` to fetch email text.

But in foundCharacters text string I am getting only upto `abc@expressl` not whole text. Its considering `&t` as a special character. And thats why after that its going in `parseErrorOccurred` delegate.

How can I avoid such errors. I cant hardcode anything to replace text. As email should print as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, that's not valid XML. The `&` character must be escaped. From [section 2.4 of the XML 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax):

> The ampersand character (`&`) and the left angle bracket (`<`) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings `&amp;` and `&lt;` respectively.

If you want to use an XML parser, you need to give it valid XML to start with. Whatever *created* the XML should have escaped it for you, to:

```
<Email>abc@expressl&amp;t.net</Email>
```

What created the XML file? This sort of thing normally happens when people build XML from strings, rather than using an XML API to create it.

Answer (score 1):

To be valid

`<Email>abc@expressl&t.net</Email>`

should be escaped to

`<Email>abc@expressl&amp;t.net</Email>`

Comment: Bah, what Jon said. My browser crashed when posting.